# Matching a regex

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

My regex skills are poor. For my js/css to show the correct menu I am adding in a "selected" class to my li so that the js knows which is the current item (so it can display the rest of the drop down).

My problem is matching the correct uri string in codeigniter:

```
<li <? if((strstr($this->uri->uri_string(),"rfid_finder/finder")) || (strstr($this->uri->uri_string(),"finder"))) {?>class="selected"<?}?>  rel="home"> <?= anchor('finder','HOME')?></li>
```

I was using this method initially but my routes are now a bit more complex to allow for searching and pagination.

I need a regex that would match all of the following routes:

```
$route['finder/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "rfid_finder/finder/$1/$2/$3";
$route['finder/(:any)/(:any)'] = "rfid_finder/finder/$1/$2";
$route['finder/(:any)'] = "rfid_finder/finder/$1";
$route['finder'] = 'rfid_finder/finder';
```

but when a user visits:

```
rfid_finder/search_form
```

the first menu is not given the selected class.

**Update**

I want first code snippet to match the routes and not the `rfid_finder/search` route- I have a second line of code which matches the rfid_finder/search_form route. my problem lies in trying to capture the route using `(strstr($this->uri->uri_string(),"finder")` it matches all my routes even the `rfid_finder/search_form`

Comment: where you wrote any, do you want any char or only letters?

Comment: :any can be a username or a tag- which should be a string (numbers and chars)

Comment: I don't understand something: so everything works, but when you go to search_form you don't want it to match, right?

Comment: i have updated the question with a better explanation of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, let me know if this works for you. It seems to work in my tests.

```
preg_match('|^(rfid_finder/)?finder/?([a-z0-9]+?)?(/[a-z0-9]+?)?(/\d+?)?$|i', $string)
```

Here's my testing example:

```
$route = array();
$route['finder/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "rfid_finder/finder/$1/$2/$3";
$route['finder/(:any)/(:any)'] = "rfid_finder/finder/$1/$2";
$route['finder/(:any)'] = "rfid_finder/finder/$1";
$route['finder'] = 'rfid_finder/finder';


$route['finder/2313'] = 'rfid_finder/finder';
$route['finder/asd/dsda'] = 'rfid_finder/finder';
$route['rfid_finder/finder/dd/122'] = 'rfid_finder/finder';
$route['rfid_finder/finder/dd/122/qwewe'] = 'rfid_finder/finder';
$route['rfid_finder/finder/dd/asdsad/333'] = 'rfid_finder/finder';

foreach ($route as $string=>$match) {
    if ( preg_match('|^(rfid_finder/)?finder/?([a-z0-9]+?)?(/[a-z0-9]+?)?(/\d+?)?$|i', $string) ) {
        echo $string.' - yes';
    } else {
        echo $string.' - no';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}

exit();
```

It searches the string to make sure it starts with either finder or rfid_finder (i wasn't really sure which you prefered. if you want it to only start with rfid_finder just remove the parentheses around rfid_finder and the trailing ? before finder)

Comment: In response to your edit. You could try using strpos instead and use the offset. Although the regex I posted above seems to do what you want (at least from what I understood)